# Bubblewrap build command fails with a java class not found exception

Tags: google-chrome, build, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, bubblewrap

I am on Windows 11 operating system, trying to convert my react website into a pwa, i have initialised bubblewrap by the init command and all the naming is done, but when i proceed to bubblewrap build command, the following error occurs.

**Installing Android Build Tools. Please, read and accept the license agreement.
build Installing Build Tools
Error: Could not find or load main class s
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: s
cli ERROR undefined**

I have allowed bubblewrap to install its own jdk and android sdk,tried deleting the bubblewrap and then installing again but nothing helped resolving this error. When i tried giving my system's jdk path, it is prompting to install only jdk 11.